# Should I Dockerize my Django app or just make a virtual env?

Tags: python, django, docker, pip, virtualenv

I developed an accounting software with django which will be only used on the local server of client's computer. My question is: How do I setup the dependencies on clients computer? Do I install all dependencies individually? Or put my project onto a virtual env and move the virtual env into the clients PC? Or should I dockerize the app?

Comment: I think this mostly depends on what tool you're most familiar with. I think Docker would be easiest, but others might disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It totally depends on the complexity of your project. Docker could be the best option, but if you have limited dependencies in your project, then virtual environment is enough.

Comment: Absolutely agree. Docker comes into play with a tradeoff. It simplifies the dependency management. However, it slightly reduces the server performance.

Answer (score 1):

Start with what you need.

> local server of client's computer

Create a python virtual env and install dependencies there. Ensure that a [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/) is created and added to source control on the project.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You may want to create a service or systemd unit file to automatically start the server when the system starts up.